# Tiling a $13 \times 11$ rectangle with squares

Tags: mathematics, dissection

What is the smallest number of integer-sided squares required to tile a $13 \times 11$ rectangle without overlaps?

Comment: I believe this is the same question that I have asked a couple of weeks ago. I might be wrong because I might misunderstand the question :)

Comment: This isn't the same -  here the squares cannot overlap and we're not trying to make a grid, just cover the rectangle

Comment: @maylor hmm you are right, sorry about that :)

Comment: @Oray How is this anything like [your post](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29711/tiling-a-13-times-11-rectangle-with-squares)?

Comment: @PaulEvans  i know i said sorry already :)

Comment: @Oray But there's two close requests saying it's a duplicate of [your post](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29711/tiling-a-13-times-11-rectangle-with-squares).

Comment: @PaulEvans so? It is not me anyway... I retracted already.

Comment: @Oray OK, But how could anyone think it's a duplicate in the first place?

Comment: @PaulEvans a misunderstanding? :)

Comment: @Oray lotta people with a lotta misunderstanding...

Comment: @PaulEvans misunderstanding happens all around, which is a normal situation, it is not even your question, why do you care this much? if you want to start a discussion, you can open a discussion...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37584/discussion-between-paul-evans-and-oray).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's:

> 6 squares.

Because:

> I originally came up with the solution by trying to divide up the $13\times 11$ rectangles into similar-ish quarters and saw this $5, 6, 7, 4, 8$ pattern that magically produced only one $1\times 1$ square in the middle bit.
>  The more I though about it the more I was convinced I wouldn't be gobsmacked by a smaller number of squares working.
>  So here's the rigor:
>  The area that needs to be covered is $143 = 13 \times 11$.
>  Generating all possible combinations of $5$ or less squares, less than or equal to $11\times 11$, that exactly cover a $143$ area yields:
>  (1, 5, 6, 9)
>  (2, 3, 3, 11)
>  (2, 3, 7, 9)
>  (3, 3, 5, 10)
>  (3, 6, 7, 7)
>  (1, 1, 2, 4, 11)
>  (1, 1, 4, 5, 10)
>  (1, 2, 5, 7, 8)
>  (1, 3, 4, 6, 9)
>  (2, 4, 5, 7, 7)
>  (2, 5, 5, 5, 8)
>  (3, 3, 3, 4, 10)
>  (3, 3, 5, 6, 8)
>  None of these work because the only one that has all combinations of pairs adding up to $13$ or less is:
>  (2, 5, 5, 5, 8)
>  And that doesn't fit into a $13\times 11$ rectangle.
>  All combinations of $6$ squares, less than or equal to $11\times 11$, that cover a $143$ area with no pairs adding up to more than $13$ are:
>  (4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6)
>  (2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7)
>  (2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8)
>  (1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6)
>  (1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)
>  (2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7)
>  Of these, only (1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7) fits into a $13\times 11$ rectangle.
>  So $6$ is the minimal number of squares, as shown below.
>  Of course, all rotations and mirror images also work.
>  [image]